# Call method a JS file that includes my file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Parent file : Parent.js

```
exports.execute = function execute(request) {
    var result = executeChild(request);  // Will not work as the executeChild function is not in this file.
    return "Hi!";
}
```

Child file : Child1.js

```
common = require('common');
execute = common.execute;
function executeChild(request) {
    return "Hello1";
}
```

Child file : Child2.js

```
common = require('common');
execute = common.execute;
function executeChild(request) {
    return "Hello2";
}
```

All the users of API call the **execute** method and they have no idea about the Parent child (*OK may be its not a real Parent child relationship*) relationship. **How to make this function call (execute child) work.**

NodeJs is used to execute this.

I would try to update the functions in the child files as a last resort and not before.

Comment: Make the child files pass in the `executeChild` function into `execute`

Comment: I don't want to change the child files. There are a lot of them.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this without changing the child files to some degree. There are mass find and replace tools that you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change common to take child function as an argument:

```
exports.execute = function execute(request, executeChild) {
    var result = executeChild(request);  
    return "Hi!";
}
```

and in "child" modules you'll be able to run (note lack of `()` after `executeChild` when calling common!)

```
function executeChild() {}
require('common').execute(request, executeChild);
```

---

If you were looking for a "magic" way of changing common's behavior by including any one of child modules, then you probably want global variables `global.executeChild`, but that's not how things are done in node. It's better to explicitly pass functions.